# Hover opacity for a different image than the one hovering

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'm using the CSS ':hover' rule to make an image 'disappear' and reappear using opacity changes.

I'm sure there's a simple code for this, but I can't find it and I'm pretty inexperienced.

I have image A. Next to image A, I have image B. Image B's opacity is set at 0. When I hover over image A, I want to change image B's opacity to 1:

```
<img class="a" src="a.jpg"> <img class="b" src="b.jpg">
```

All the examples I found for this kind of thing were for changing image A's opacity when you hover over image A, but I'm looking to change image B's opacity when I hover over image A.

How can I alter this code

`image.A:hover { opacity:1; }`

To affect image B?

Comment: As requested here's some code  

`<img class="a" src="a.jpg">


<img class="b" src="b.jpg">`

Comment: I've already added the image elements into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stab in the dark:

```
img.A:hover + img.B { opacity: 1 }
```

Comment: This is pretty much the only sibling selector available in CSS. Everything else applies to children

Comment: Looks promising but I can't get this to work... Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @helion3 are you telling me there's no way to get this to work?

Comment: There may be no way but we need to know what your html looks like, the dom structure is what matters to css selectors.

Comment: If the img elements are direct siblings like your example, this css solution will work. However, just want to say that `opacity` and the `+` sibling selector won't work properly in older IE

Comment: @helion3 Which version of IE you mean? It works on IE7+ well.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use jQuery to accomplish this more efficiently in more browsers. Older browsers do not support new CSS3 properties.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imageA').hover(function(){
        $('.imageB').animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 500);
    }, function(){
        $('.imageB').animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Check out my example

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5c9q/

---

If you need to accomplish this with just css, this is how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5c9q/1/

Comment: That's great man, even threw in some smooth fade effects but for this one I absolutely gotta use HTML & CSS alone. Care to provide the CSS3 property anyways?

Comment: Yeh sure. I updated my answer. Take a look at the second example